# Retrieve generated IDs when doing bulk insert using Spring Data R2DBC

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

I have a scenario where my table has an autogenerated id column and **I need to bulk insert items into db and fetch the generated ids**. Is there any way I can achieve that?

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  `id` SERIAL NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

To save a list of items into this table, the code I am using:

```
String initialSql = "INSERT INTO test_table(`name`,`created_date`) VALUES ";

    List<String> values =
        dummyEntities.stream()
            .map(dummyEntity -> "('" + dummyEntity.getName() + "','"
                + dummyEntity.getCreatedDate().atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime().toString() + "')")
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    String sqlToExecute =  initialSql + String.join(",", values);
    client.execute(sqlToExecute)
             .//Then what?
```

The generated SQL statement (from DEBUG Logs):

```
2020-09-15 18:59:32.613 DEBUG 44801 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] o.s.d.r2dbc.core.DefaultDatabaseClient   : Executing SQL statement [INSERT INTO test_table(`name`,`created_date`) VALUES ('Abhi57','2020-09-15T13:29:29.951964'),('Abhi92','2020-09-15T13:29:29.952023')]
```

I even tried using `ConnectionFactory`, still no clue

```
    Mono.from(connectionFactory.create())
        .map(Connection::createBatch)
        .map(batch -> {
          dummyEntities.forEach(dummyEntity -> {
            String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO `test_table` (`name`,`created_date`) VALUES ('%s','%s');", dummyEntity.getName(),
                dummyEntity.getCreatedDate().atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toLocalDateTime().toString());
            batch.add(sql);
          });
          return batch;
        })
        .flatMap(batch -> Mono.from(batch.execute()))
        .//Then what?
```

For reference, `dummyEntities` variable holds a list of `DummyEntity` objects. And the `DummyEntity` class looks like this:

```
@Table("test_table")
public class DummyEntity implements Persistable<Long> {

  @Id
  @Column("id")
  private Long id;

  @Column("name")
  private String name;

  @Column("created_date")
  private OffsetDateTime createdDate;

  //Getter,Setter
  @Override
  public boolean isNew() {
    return id == null;
  }
}
```

Dependencies used: 2.3.2.RELEASE

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc'
    implementation 'dev.miku:r2dbc-mysql:0.8.2.RELEASE'
```

Comment: What you are looking for is `client.execute( ... ).all()` documented here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/1.1.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#r2dbc.datbaseclient.queries depending on the query you get different objects back but i think its `all()` you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Using the original `ConnectionFacotory` is easy to get generated ids.

I have tried to use `ConnectionFactory` to get the generated ids, worked as expected.

```java
                    .thenMany(
                            Mono.from(conn)
                                    .flatMapMany(
                                            c -> c.createStatement(insertSql)
                                                    .returnGeneratedValues("id")
                                                    .execute()

                                    )
                    )
                    .flatMap(data -> Flux.from(data.map((row, rowMetadata) -> row.get("id"))))
                    .doOnNext(id -> log.info("generated id: {}", id))
```

The complete code example is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/connection-factories/src/test/java/com/example/demo/H2Tests.java#L71-L91).

It prints logs in the console like this.

```sh
2020-09-19 10:43:30,815 INFO [main] com.example.demo.H2Tests$Sql:89 generated id: 1
2020-09-19 10:43:30,815 INFO [main] com.example.demo.H2Tests$Sql:89 generated id: 2
```

And I think the new `DatabaseClient`  in Spring framework 5.3 is just a thin wrapper of the connectionfactories,and use a `filter` to get generated ids.

```java
databaseClient.sql("INSERT INTO  posts (title, content, metadata) VALUES (:title, :content, :metadata)")
.filter((statement, executeFunction) -> statement.returnGeneratedValues("id").execute())
```

Check [the complete example codes](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/database-client/src/main/java/com/example/demo/PostRepository.java#L59)(but this example only retrieve a single id).

Comment: Hi @Hantsy , sorry for such late response. I tried out your code. But it returns only a single generated id (the first id of the batch). Check it out here: https://friendpaste.com/10LKeGYsUF2OJWPUjzrDh7 . Can you please point out what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure the exact reason in your codes, can not determine it from the code fragment. I tried my codes, it is working as expected.

Comment: are you using the same Miku Mysql driver? From the code snippet you shared it was for H2.

Comment: Tried MySQL, yeah, it only returns the last id. Maybe it is from statement `last_insert_id`.

Comment: Yeah, How does the non-reactive driver returns all generated ids? There must be some way..Isn't it @Hantsy ?

Comment: Different database varied, pg added a `returning id` to return the inserted it.

Comment: Ofcouse different db drivers have different logic (like you mentioned for postgres)... but what I am curious about is that  - How does Spring's non-reactive library (the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa with the mysql cj jdbc Driver ) returns all the persisted entities (with generated ids) ? If it's possible in non-reactive world , then it should be possible here too.. @Hantsy

Comment: When using data jpa to save a collection of data, it inserted then one by one I think, it also worked with mysql and r2dbc, check [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/connection-factories/src/test/java/com/example/demo/MySQLTests.java#L121).

Comment: Ok I see that using this statement bind and add method is inserting one by one..Do you know if the returned generated id flux contains ids of the rows are in the same order as the list of records I am trying to insert? @Hantsy

Comment: Looks like with MSSQL also if you call `.returnGeneratedValues("id")` before `execute()` , it returns only the last id. But if you specify `Output Inserted.id` in the `INSERT` statement itself, then all the generated ids are returned. Unfortunately MySQL doesnt support such.

Answer (score 2):

Late response, but since i faced the same issue on R2DBC PostgreSQL, here is a possible solution:

```
// -- generate 100 Product entities and mark them as CREATE
// -- Product is implementing Persistable<UUID> and isNew() will return TRUE for CREATE and FALSE for UPDATE 
List<Product> list = Stream.generate(() -> Product.builder()
    .articleNumber(UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 10))
    .name(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    .images(Arrays.asList("1", "2"))
    .saveAction(SaveAction.CREATE)
    .build()).limit(100).collect(Collectors.toList());

// -- create the PostgresqlBatch and return the Result flux
Flux<? extends Result> flux = databaseClient.inConnectionMany(connection -> {
  Batch batch = connection.createBatch();

  list.forEach(p -> {
    batch.add("INSERT INTO product(\"id\",\"article_number\",\"name\") VALUES ('" + p.getId() + "','" + p.getArticleNumber() + "','" + p
        .getName() + "') RETURNING id, name, article_number");
  });

  return Flux.from(batch.execute());
});

// -- transform the Result flux into a Product flux
return flux.flatMap(result -> result.map((row, rowMetadata) -> Product.builder()
    .id(row.get("id", UUID.class))
    .name(row.get("name", String.class))
    .articleNumber(row.get("article_number", String.class))
    .build()));
```

The *secret* is **RETURNING column1, column2, column3** added to each insert statement.